# How to create shaded mesh in opengles on android

Tags: android, opengl-es

In my application I'm trying to create a mesh that is shaded by a single directional light. The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to get the light to take my normals into account at all.

It works fine if I set the normals on a per-triangle-strip basis, but if I try to render a series of triangles with normals set using the `glNormalPointer` method the entire mesh is rendered using the same color (which is identical to the result I'm getting if I skip calling `glNormalPointer` all together).

My mesh render method looks like this:

public void render(GL10 gl) {
  gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
  gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalBuffer);
  gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
  gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indexBuffer.capacity(), GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should call](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml)

```
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was driving me nuts.